# Image processing understanding

Tags: java, image-processing

```
public void Only_GREEN() 
{

    for(int y=0;y<bi.getHeight();y++)
    {

        for(int x=0;x<bi.getWidth();x++)
        {

            int rgb = bi.getRGB(x, y);
            Color c = new Color(rgb);

            int r=c.getGreen();

            rgb = (0xff000000) | (0 << 16) | (r << 8) | (0 << 0);
            System.out.println("hi",rgb);
            bi.setRGB(x, y, rgb);

        }

    }

}
```

This is some code for painting a picture green. I can't understand the following two lines:

```
int r=c.getGrenn()
rgb = (0xff000000) | (0 << 16) | (r << 8) | (0 << 0);
```

What do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume `a = 0xf000` and `b = 0x000f`.

`x | y` is a [bitwise or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR). Every bit in either `x`, `y`, or both will be set to `1` on the resulting output. `a | b` will become `0xf00f`. `b | b` will become `0x000f`.

`x << num` is a [left shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_shift#Bit_shifts). Every bit in `x` will be shifted `num` places to the left. Values that are shifted out on the left are lost, new values on the right will be zero. `b << 4` will become `0x00f0` and `a << 4` will become `0x0000`.

So, let's break down the code you selected. The first part appears to just get the green value as an int (which will have a bit representation). The second part is more interesting:

```
// Start
rgb = (0xff000000) | (0 << 16) | (r << 8) | (0 << 0);

// 1. Do the parts in parentheses. Notice the green value was shifted over two bits
rgb = 0xff000000 | 0x00000000 | 0x0000rr00 | 0x00000000;

// 2. Apply the ORs
rgb = 0xff00rr00;
```

So what's happening? It looks like this sets the alpha (first two bytes) to all 1's so the color is opaque. It then zeros out the red (second two bytes) and blue (last two bytes). It keeps the green color, bit shifting it into the green portion of the RGB representation. This works because the [RGB hex representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Shorthand_hexadecimal_form) looks like `0xAARRGGBB`, where A is alpha, R is red, G is green, and B is blue.

Comment: Hey thnx but could you please tell me what is the exact value of r in bits after r=c.getGreen();

Comment: @user2485269 It will be whatever value is returned by `getGreen()`. In this case, it looks like it's the green value for the pixel at the given point on the bitmap `bi` (note the for loops going through the length and width of the image). It should be an integer between 0 (`0x00`) and 255 (`0xff`), which can be represented in two bytes. Java uses signed integers, so the underlying bits will be something like `0x00...0gg`, where `gg` is the green value.

Answer (score 1):

The getGreen() function returns the value of the green portion of the color.

Colors are often represented in hex code with six characters, the first two characters are red, next two characters green, last two characters are blue.

`(r<<8)` shifts the two green characters over two characters, so it fits into the standard hex color code. Two hex characters are 8 bits long, which is why it is shifted left by 8, to place the green value in the correct space.